# How can I align three pictures with corresponding text so that they alternate left to right?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to create a simple "about Us" page for our company website and I am having troubles with alignment in CSS and HTML. The basic idea is this:

```
--Pic-- --Text-

--Text-- --Pic-

--Pic-- --Text-
```

Here is the HTML code I have created:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="baseStyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="aboutUsStyles.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <h1>who are we?</h1>

<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="ourProducts.html">Our Products</a></li>
<li><a href="FAQ.html">FAQs</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content">

<div><p id="andypic">
    <img src="http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/7106/testjdc.jpg"></p>
<p id="andyPicInfo">This is a test
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg   
</p>
</div>

<div><p id="evpic">
<img src="http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/7106/testjdc.jpg"></p>
<p id="andyPicInfo">This is a test
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg   
</p>
</div>    

<div><p id="tannerpic">
    <img src="http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/7106/testjdc.jpg"></p>
<p id="andyPicInfo">This is a test
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
testgfgfdfgdfgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg   
</p>
</div>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here are the two CSS files:

The first file:

```
#nav {
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 3em 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }

#nav li {
float: left; }

#nav li a {
display: block;
padding: 8px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #069;
border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }

#nav li a:hover {
color: #c00;
background-color: #fff; }

body {
background-color: #555; 
font: small/1.3 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

#wrap {
width: 750px;
height: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #fff; }

h1 {
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.5em;
padding: 1em 8px;
color: #123;
background-color: #069;
margin: 0; }

#content {
padding: 0 30px 30px; }

#copyright { 
text-align: center;
font-size: .75em; }
```

The second file:

```
#andypic{
float: left;
height: 240px;
width: 320px;
}

#evpic{
float: right;
height: 240px;
width: 320px;
}
#tannerpic{
float: left;
height: 240px;
width: 320px;
}
```

What I have now is almost ok, but the lines are all wrong and the text isn't matching properly.

Now I know this looks weird here on SO but it looks something like this now: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to simplify things a bit for you. The relevant CSS I came up with is this:

```
.person {
    clear: both;  /* make every new person start beneath the previous */
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.person img {
    display: block;
    height: 240px;
    width: 320px;
}

/* fallback for browser that don't support the nth-child */
.person img {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

/* float odd pictures to the left */
.person:nth-child(2n+1) img {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
}

/* float even pictures to the right */
.person:nth-child(2n) img {
    float: right;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}
```

To see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/eYrNY/

Note that this uses the CSS3 nth-child selector. For browser support, have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-child  I also added a fallback for legacy (read <IE9) browsers, so they will show all the pictures to the left in stead of alternating them.

Note that I made a few changes to the HTML as well:
 - I removed the `<p>` tags around the images. Semantically incorrect and not necessary. Just set your images to display block.
 - I removed the id's from the persons info and the image wrapper (you could add them back if you require them elsewhere, but in my example they are no longer required), and added a class of 'person' to the wrapping div for each person.

The advantage of this method is that you can add an infinite amount of persons, or change their order, without ever having to add or change an other line of CSS...

Comment: Wow thanks! :) thats quite simple, I am still learning all of this! I like the infinite person list idea, its a great add. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Clear your floats between rows.

```
--Pic-- --Text-

<div class="clearfix"></div>

--Text-- --Pic-

<div class="clearfix"></div>

--Pic-- --Text-
```

CSS

```
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

This will stop the rows overlapping each other as in your picture.

Some padding around the text would help too

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your CSS :

```
#content > div { clear:both; }
```

Basically, floated elements need to be "neutralized" by using clear so it won't overlap/mess other elements. Btw this answer does not need additional html code